# Question about the proof of the min-max principle

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a densely defined self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ which is bounded from below. The min-max principle states that:
$$\mu_{n}(A) := \inf_{\substack{M \subset D(A) \\ \text{dim}M = n}}\sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1}}\langle \psi, A\psi\rangle$$
is an increasing sequence $\mu_{n}(A) \to \mu_{\infty}(A) := \inf \sigma_{\text{ess}}(A)$. Moreover, if $\mu_{n}(A) < \mu_{\infty}(A)$ then $\mu_{n}(A)$ is the $n$-th lowest eigenvalue of $A$.

I am trying to understand the proof of the second part of this result. I already proved that $\mu_{1}(A)$ is the lowest eigenvalue of $A$ if $\mu_{1}(A) < \mu_{\infty}(A)$. Suppose then $\mu_{2}(A) < \mu_{\infty}(A)$. Since $\mu_{1}(A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, we can choose an associated eigenvector  $\varphi$. Of course we can decompose $\mathscr{H} = \text{span}\{\varphi\}\oplus W$, where $W = \{\varphi\}^{\perp}$. Let $A_{W}$ be the restriction of $A$ to $W$. Here is my question: the proof states that:
$$\mu_{2}(A) = \inf_{\substack{\psi \in W \\ \|\psi\| =1 }}\langle \psi, A_{W}\psi\rangle \equiv \mu_{1}(A_{W}).$$
Why is this true?

Comment: Do you have additional hypotheses on $A$? Otherwise, there is no reason for $A$ to have eigenvalues at all.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I think there are no further hypothesis. See e.g. Thm 6.1 on page 73 here: https://uol.de/f/5/inst/mathe/personen/konstantin.pankrashkin/spectral-oldb-2020.pdf

Comment: There is a crucial assumption there. Namely that $\lambda_n(A)$ are strictly less than the infimum of the essential spectrum.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc but this is what I am assuming in my post. If $\mu_{n} < \mu_{\infty}$ then it is an eigenvalue. And I am also assuming that for $\mu_{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, the message was addressed to @MartinArgerami

Comment: What is $A_1$? If it is the same as $A_W$ then it is unclear why it is defined on the whole $W$ instead of $D(A)\cap W$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky yes, thanks. I fixed the notation.

Comment: Question now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454808/question-about-a-step-in-the-proof-of-the-min-max-principle

Comment: $A_W:D(A_W)\to W$ is self-adjoint operator bounded from below with $\mu_\infty(A_W)= \mu_\infty(A)$ and $D(A_W)\oplus \text{span}\{\phi\} = D(A)$ and $A = A_W\oplus \mu_1I.$ Does this statement look sufficient for complete proof?

Answer (score 0):

Please point exact p. or equality number to clarify.

1. $A_W:D(A_W)\to W$ is self-adjoint operator bounded from below.
2. $D(A_W)\oplus \text{span}\{\phi\} = D(A), A = A_W\oplus \mu_1(X)I$ where $I$ is identity map on $\text{span}\{\phi\}=\mathbb{C}\phi.$
3. $\mu_\infty(A)=\mu_\infty(A_W).$

\begin{align}
    E &:= \inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \\ \text{dim}M = 2}}
    \sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1}}
   \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle \\
             & \overset{1}{=} \inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \\ \text{dim}M = 2}}
    \sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1 \\ \psi\perp\phi}}
   \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle \\
             & \overset{2}{=} \inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \\ \text{dim}M = 2}}
    \sup_{\substack{\psi \in M\cap W \\ \|\psi\| = 1 }}
    \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle \\
             & \overset{3}{=} \inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \cap W \\ \text{dim}M \in \{1,2\} }}
    \sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1 }}
    \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle
\end{align}

Simplify last expression:
\begin{align}
\inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \cap W \\ \text{dim}M = 2}}
    \sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1 }}
    \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle \overset{4}{\ge} 
\inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \cap W \\ \text{dim}M = 1}}
    \sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1 }}
    \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle
\end{align}

Continue:
\begin{align}
  E &\overset{6}{=} \inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \cap W \\ \text{dim}M = 1}}
    \sup_{\substack{\psi \in M \\ \|\psi\| = 1 }}
    \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle \\
             &\overset{7}{=} \inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A) \cap W \\ \text{dim}M = 1 \\ \|\psi\| = 1}}
    \langle \psi, A\psi\rangle \\
             &\overset{8}{=} \inf_{
    \substack{M \subset D(A_W) \\ \text{dim}M = 1 \\ \|\psi\| = 1}}
    \langle \psi, A_W\psi\rangle \\
             &\overset{9}{=} \mu_1(A_W).
\end{align}

4. Equality (9) by p.1 and 3
5. Equality (2) by p.2.
6. By p. 2 $\mu_1(A_W)$ is eigenvalue of $A.$
7. Similar to inequality 4, $E \ge \mu_1(A).$
8. Assumption $E > \mu_2(A) \ge \mu_1(A)$ leads to contradiction at equality (1).
9. Eq. (6): $\inf_{M_1\cup M_2} = \inf_{M_1}$ if $\inf_{M_2} \ge \inf_{M_1}$ and $M_1 \neq \emptyset.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First of all, I think you used the notation $M$ for two different things: in my case $M$ is a subspace of $D(A)$ and I think your $M$ after point 3 should be $\mu_{2}(A)$ by definition. Moreover, equalities 6 to 9 should actually be inequalities, right? By inequality 4. But then you conclude $\mu_{2}(A) \ge \mu_{1}(A_{W})$, not the equality.

Comment: I missed restriction on norm for eq. 6-9. Renamed $M$ to avoid confusion. Check updated version.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Still don't get why eqs. 6 to 9 are equalities, since equation 6 should be an inequality by 4.

Comment: No, $\inf_{M_1\cup M_2} = \inf_{M_1}$ if $\inf_{M_2} \ge \inf_{M_1}$ and $M_1 \neq \emptyset.$